# I need to change the format of date while retrieving from database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

I am having this code to populate my grid:

```
protected void fillGrid()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)db.ExecuteSql("select b.*,bl.StartDate,bl.EndDate from " + schemaname + ".ClaimMaster b," + schemaname + ".ClaimMaster_Link bl where b.IsDeleted=0 and b.ClaimCode=bl.ClaimCode order by ClaimCode desc ", "");
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

the date that is being retrieved is in the form `dd/mm/yyyy`.
the data stored in the database is `2015-07-02 17:15:47.000`

but I need to populate my `gridview` with the date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: Do you need it to be a string or DateTime object?

Comment: Load the date to a date time variable and then use overridden ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")

Comment: Use `DataFormatString` property ( if `BoundField` is used )

Comment: *"the data stored in the database is 2015-07-02 17:15:47.000"* No it's not. Its being returned in the format `DateTime` and the default way to display a DateTime object in Sql Management Studio is to display it the way you see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select convert(varchar,YourDateColumn,103) from YourTable
```

For all types of date conversion please visit [Here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name
where convert(varchar,column_name,103)='02/07/2015'
```

see this link for any type of date convert:-

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: Error will occur in this query. Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Value' to data type int.

Comment: Your query should be like this:- select * from table_name where convert(varchar,column_name,103)='02/07/2015' and this is not what the user asked the question for it. It will only check the condition for date and will not convert the date to dd/MM/yyyy.